# OpenGL EBO vs Mesh representation

Tags: opengl, 3d-meshes

As an exercise set to myself, I wanted to make a Mesh loader using modern OpenGL.

However, I have to ways of representing the notion of *face* of a mesh.

Currently, I am using what seems the most natural. A mesh contains a

```
std::vector<Triangle>
```

and a Triangle is simply

```
struct Triangle
{
    unsigned int Vertices[3];
}
```

(i.e. each triangle stores the three indices of its vertices).
NOTE : a mesh contains others things (such as the vertices and the normals but I didn't include them here for simplicity).

However, OpenGL require a different representation for using EBO : only one static array on indices (implicitly grouped by 3).

What I have come up with is a trade-off between these representations : once the mesh is loaded, I generate a static array of size

```
3 * mesh->Faces.size()
```

but I assume this is not the best option for memory use and redundancy.

So my questions are :

- If I want to keep my current representation of a mesh (with a vector of faces), how should I set OpenGL to properly render such a mesh ? Is my current solution of generating a new static a good practice ?
- Assuming I can use the representation I want for my mesh. What would you recommand and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your current way is fine.

C++ struct layout will let you turn the `Triangle*` into a `int*` and store that into the EBO.

Comment: Thanks ! And how should I turn properly turn the std::vector<Triangle> to my unsigned int* that OpenGL require ?

Comment: vector has a `data()` function that'll return the `Triangle*` which you can cast to the `int*`.